# chromedriver disable log statements

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am using chrome driver version  2.33.506120
When I run the tests I see the logs like this :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 21961
Only local connections are allowed.
Jan 03, 2018 11:25:37 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Jan 03, 2018 11:25:37 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

Is there any way to disable this type of logs ?

> Note: I tried many things like chrome options, "--disable-logging",
>   "--log-level", capabilities etc as suggested in other places but none
>   of them seems to work.

My code looks like this:

```
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverLocationClass.getChromeDriverLocation());
/*              System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "NUL");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
*/
                DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

                HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
                chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory",
                        systemProperties.getProperty(AppConstants.SYS_KEY_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION));              

                options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
                options.addArguments("--disable-logging");

                cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);


                LoggingPreferences pref = new LoggingPreferences();
                pref.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.SEVERE);
                cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, pref);

                cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

/*              LoggingPreferences loggingPreferences = new LoggingPreferences();
                loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.SEVERE);
                loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.SEVERE);

                cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPreferences);*/

                d = new ChromeDriver(cap);
                d.manage().window().maximize();
```